# Making and sorting index for Serbian (cyrilic)

Tags: indexing, sorting, cyrillic

How to make and sort index on cyrilic alphabet?

Trying to make index with Serbian words:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[OT1, OT2]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, serbian]{babel}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[name=person,title={Indeks imena},options=-s index_style.ist]

\makeindex[program=makeindex,columns=2,intoc=true,options=-s index_style.ist]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Pitagora}

\index[person]{Pitagora|text}

\index[person]{Riman|text}

\index[person]{Vijet|text}

\index[person]{Gaus|text}

\printindex[person]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You're using Cyrillic by default, so that's how the names are interpreted.

Comment: Yes, names are interpreted, but not sorted. For example: Vijet, Gaus, Pitagora and Riman.

Comment: What's in `index_style.ist`?

Comment: Anyway, MakeIndex only sorts using ASCII.

Comment: index_style.ist is file: headings_flag 1

heading_prefix "{\\large\\bfseries "

heading_suffix "}\\nopagebreak\n"

delim_0 " \\dotfill "
delim_1 " \\dotfill "
delim_2 " \\dotfill "

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[OT1, OT2]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, serbian]{babel}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}

\makeindex[program=truexindy,name=person,title={Indeks imena},options=-M mystyle.xdy]

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mystyle.xdy}
(require "lang/serbian/utf8-lang.xdy")
(require "texindy.xdy")
(define-letter-groups
    ("A" "B" "V" "G" "D" "DJ" "E" "ZH" "Z" "I" "J" "K" "L" "LJ" "M"
     "N" "NJ" "O" "P" "R" "S" "T" "C1" "U" "F" "H" "C" "CH" "D2" "SH"))
(sort-rule "a" "A")
(sort-rule "b" "B")
(sort-rule "v" "V")
(sort-rule "g" "G")
(sort-rule "d" "D")
(sort-rule "Dj" "DJ")
(sort-rule "dj" "DJ")
(sort-rule "e" "E")
(sort-rule "Zh" "ZH")
(sort-rule "zh" "ZH")
(sort-rule "z" "Z")
(sort-rule "i" "I")
(sort-rule "j" "J")
(sort-rule "k" "K")
(sort-rule "l" "L")
(sort-rule "Lj" "LJ")
(sort-rule "lj" "LJ")
(sort-rule "m" "M")
(sort-rule "n" "N")
(sort-rule "Nj" "NJ")
(sort-rule "nj" "NJ")
(sort-rule "o" "O")
(sort-rule "p" "P")
(sort-rule "r" "R")
(sort-rule "s" "S")
(sort-rule "t" "T")
(sort-rule "c1" "C1")
(sort-rule "u" "U")
(sort-rule "f" "F")
(sort-rule "h" "H")
(sort-rule "c" "C")
(sort-rule "Ch" "CH")
(sort-rule "ch" "CH")
(sort-rule "d2" "D2")
(sort-rule "Sh" "SH")
(sort-rule "sh" "SH")
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Pitagora}

\index[person]{Pitagora}

\index[person]{Riman}

\index[person]{Vijet}

\index[person]{Gaus}

\printindex[person]

\end{document}
```

Then you compile like this:

```
pdflatex yourFile.tex
xindy -M mystyle.xdy -L serbian person.idx
pdflatex yourFile.tex
```

But be careful! Letters you get as a combination with number, such as `c1` or `d2` will be sorted wrong. Always is better to use `utf8` input and `T2A` encoding rather than `OT2` with `ASCII` input.

P.S. For Serbian I always recommend to use package [cmsrb](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cmsrb).  In new version I created experimental encodings where you can use `dx cy` for `џ ћ` so the results with sorting will be better.

**EDIT:**

After some playing with `xindy`, I've found another solution where the problems with a letters that are created like a ligature with number for `OT2` encoding, such as `c1` for `ћ`, can be solved. Also, for Serbian language the letter group is already defined, therefore there is no need to write it again, we will just map Latin letter or ligature to the corresponding Cyrillic UTF-8 letter.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[OT1, OT2]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, serbian]{babel}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}

\makeindex[program=xindy,name=person,title={Indeks imena},columns=1]

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mystyle.xdy}
(require "texindy.xdy")
(merge-rule "DJ" "Ђ" :again)
(merge-rule "Dj" "Ђ" :again)
(merge-rule "dj" "Ђ" :again)
(merge-rule "ZH" "Ж" :again)
(merge-rule "Zh" "Ж" :again)
(merge-rule "zh" "Ж" :again)
(merge-rule "LJ" "Љ" :again)
(merge-rule "Lj" "Љ" :again)
(merge-rule "lj" "Љ" :again)
(merge-rule "NJ" "Њ" :again)
(merge-rule "Nj" "Њ" :again)
(merge-rule "nj" "Њ" :again)
(merge-rule "C1" "Ћ" :again)
(merge-rule "c1" "Ћ" :again)
(merge-rule "CH" "Ч" :again)
(merge-rule "Ch" "Ч" :again)
(merge-rule "ch" "Ч" :again)
(merge-rule "D2" "Џ" :again)
(merge-rule "d2" "Џ" :again)
(merge-rule "SH" "Ш" :again)
(merge-rule "Sh" "Ш" :again)
(merge-rule "sh" "Ш" :again)
(merge-rule "A" "А" :again)
(merge-rule "a" "А" :again)
(merge-rule "B" "Б" :again)
(merge-rule "b" "Б" :again)
(merge-rule "V" "В" :again)
(merge-rule "v" "В" :again)
(merge-rule "G" "Г" :again)
(merge-rule "g" "Г" :again)
(merge-rule "D" "Д" :again)
(merge-rule "d" "Д" :again)
(merge-rule "E" "Е" :again)
(merge-rule "e" "Е" :again)
(merge-rule "Z" "З" :again)
(merge-rule "z" "З" :again)
(merge-rule "I" "И" :again)
(merge-rule "i" "И" :again)
(merge-rule "J" "Ј" :again)
(merge-rule "j" "Ј" :again)
(merge-rule "K" "К" :again)
(merge-rule "k" "К" :again)
(merge-rule "L" "Л" :again)
(merge-rule "l" "Л" :again)
(merge-rule "M" "М" :again)
(merge-rule "m" "М" :again)
(merge-rule "N" "Н" :again)
(merge-rule "n" "Н" :again)
(merge-rule "O" "О" :again)
(merge-rule "o" "О" :again)
(merge-rule "P" "П" :again)
(merge-rule "p" "П" :again)
(merge-rule "R" "Р" :again)
(merge-rule "r" "Р" :again)
(merge-rule "S" "С" :again)
(merge-rule "s" "С" :again)
(merge-rule "T" "Т" :again)
(merge-rule "t" "Т" :again)
(merge-rule "U" "У" :again)
(merge-rule "u" "У" :again)
(merge-rule "F" "Ф" :again)
(merge-rule "f" "Ф" :again)
(merge-rule "H" "Х" :again)
(merge-rule "h" "Х" :again)
(merge-rule "C" "Ц" :again)
(merge-rule "c" "Ц" :again)
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Pitagora}

\index[person]{Pitagora}

\index[person]{Riman}

\index[person]{Vijet}

\index[person]{Gaus}

\printindex[person]

\end{document}
```

After that, compile your code with:

```
pdflatex yourFile.tex
xindy -M mystyle.xdy -C utf8 -L serbian person.idx
pdflatex yourFile.tex
```

Of course, if you want to use some other ligatures, like `d1` for `ђ`, you will have to add line `(merge-rule "d1" "Ђ" :again)`.

[image: xindy Serbian OT2]