# How to make custom sorted bibliography by Serbian Latin and Cyrillic letters?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I want to sort my bibliography by Serbian Latin and Cyrillic.
The order of sorting which I want is:
A
А
B
Б
C
Ц
Č
Ч
Ć
Ћ
D
Д
Dž
Џ
Đ
Ђ
E
Е
F
Ф
G
Г
H
Х
I
И
J
Ј
K
К
L
Л
Lj
Љ
M
М
N
Н
Nj
Њ
O
О
P
П
R
Р
S
С
Š
Ш
T
Т
U
У
V
В
Z
З
Ž
Ж

The double letters aren't double. The first is Latin and the second is Cyrillic. The sorting should be like authoryear but ordered by these letters.

Compile with XeLaTeX
MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[serbian]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \parencite[42]{hegel1975}, 

ipsusm \parencite[122]{eliot1963}, 

loremipsum \parencite[33]{petkovic2006}

\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

ref.bib file

```
@book{hegel1975,
author       =  {Georg Vilhelm Fridrih Hegel},
title        =  {Istorija filozofije},
year         =  {1975},
publisher    =  {Beogradski izdavačko-grafički zavod},
location     =  {Beograd},
edition      =  {treće izdanje},
translator   =  {Dr Nikola M. Popović}
}
@book{eliot1963,
author       =  {T.S. Eliot},
title        =  {Izabrani tekstovi},
year         =  {1963},
publisher    =  {Prosveta},
location     =  {Beograd},
translator   =  {Milica Mihailović}
}
@book{petkovic2006,
author       =  {Радослав Петковић},
title        =  {Византијски интернет},
year         =  {2006},
publisher    =  {Стубови културе},
location     =  {Београд}
}
```

T.S. Eliot should go after Радослав Петковић in the bibliography.

Comment: I saw a similar question but it isn't for bibliographies but for indexing. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/536521/making-and-sorting-index-for-serbian-cyrilic

Comment: well start by providing a small example (including a sample bib file) that can be used for tests.

Comment: Here is the bib file: https://gist.github.com/Fooftilly/a4f0f03076308bf9fdf0fae694cb057e

Comment: I wrote "provide an example *including* a bib file", not "provide *only* a bib file". It is *your* problem, so *you* should spent the time to setup a sensible test environment with all needed files.

Comment: Sorry, I edited it.

Comment: your example errors with pdflatex and with lualatex the cyrillic doesn't show up. But beside this the sorting is as you wrote it above in your list: E, H, П.

Comment: I am sorry again, I am using xelatex. The problem isn't with sorting Cyrillic and Latin separately but I want them all sorted together. Ex. if I had John Smith in the list of the authors after him Јован Јовановић should go. The problem is that computers see these characters as completely different from each other, and biblatex sorts from Latin A first and goes to the end of Latin characters, then starts from Cyrillic A , and sort the Cyrillic list to the end, second.

Comment: You want a good answer from  someone who really thought about your problem, so provide first a good question which shows that you really thought about how to present it. Don't be lazy and simply copy some arbitrary code hoping that it fits. Test your examples.

Comment: Did you try to add field like `sortname = {Radoslav Petković}` in `.bib` file?

Comment: Thanks, that worked.

Comment: Biber uses Perl's [`Unicode::Collate::Locale`](https://perldoc.perl.org/Unicode::Collate::Locale) for localised sorting. If the sort order you want is not available in that module I don't think you can easily get it. Not sure if it is possible to request a new locale for `Unicode::Collate::Locale`. Of course you could ask Biber to implement custom sort locales (https://github.com/plk/biber/issues).

Comment: As @Урош wrote, aux transliteration to Latin script will do.

Comment: That said, if the problem can be handled by automatic transliteration, that would also be an option. Biber supports auto-transliteration, but at the moment it does only Sanskrit IAST to Devanāgarī, ALA-LC romanisation for Russian and BGN/PCGN:1947 for Russian. If Serbian needs some other scheme (I assume it does) you could discuss adding that at https://github.com/plk/biber/issues (if it is available in the Perl universe).

Comment: As Урош suggested above sortname = {Author} solves the problem for sorting. The unexpected problem is that I can't set where to use Cyrillic and where Latin Serbian in the list. I need Serbian Latin for the whole document and only Serbian Cyrillic on some bibliography entries where thing like Translated by should be in Cyrillic and everywhere else in Latin. I opened the issue here: https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/348

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be solved by using `sortname` field in bib file:

```
@book{eliot1963,
author       =  {T.S. Eliot},
title        =  {Izabrani tekstovi},
year         =  {1963},
publisher    =  {Prosveta},
location     =  {Beograd},
translator   =  {Milica Mihailović},
sortname     =  {T.S. Eliot}
}
@book{petkovic2006,
author       =  {Радослав Петковић},
title        =  {Византијски интернет},
year         =  {2006},
publisher    =  {Стубови културе},
location     =  {Београд},
sortname     =  {Radoslav Petković}
}
```

You will need to write the name of the author in `sortname` field using Latin script in order to have consistent sorting. Use Cyrillic if you want Cyrillic sorting.